# Different database context for same EF model (database)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Is possible to add another database context for the same EF model (database)? I have a situation where the db context must change depends on what kind of user is logged in.

Comment: Yes.  But if this is Code-First you would enable Migrations or database Initialization on only one of them, of course. You can even have a _master_ DbContext that has all your entities that you only use for Migrations..

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell - YES. The underlying MODEL is simply a class representation of your database tables, so the trick here is to make the connection by using a different database driver as presented by Entity Framework.

EG:
Implement a repository pattern inside a class and call it MySqlContext, where this class inherits from DbContext, and this will have the OnConfiguring method:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        using (var secretsClient = new InsightSecrets())
        {
            var connectionInfo = // here you add your own depending on environment and project
            string connectionString = connectionInfo.ConnectionString;

            optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString);
        }
    }
```

The optionsBuilder instance can then create in this case above, either a MySql or Postgress reference - while this repository will then be instantiated higher up in  your code by doing something like this inside a class constructor, where this context will be used:

```
var ctx = new MySqlContext();
```

The repository called MySqlContext can in this example already provide either MySql or Postgres, but nothing stop you from implementing another repository that provides a different database context depending on the associated db drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a different `DbContext` class or just a different database? The `DbContext` class is a bridge between the database and your entities (EF model). This bridge can be used to transfer data from/to different databases. Creating a different `DbContext` class for the same EF model doesn't make much sence to me; unless i'm missing something...

But you can do both. If you're looking for a another connection to a database, then
this would be your `DbContext` class, your "bridge":

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AnotherFoo> AFoos { get; set; }

    public TestContext() : this("TestDB1") { }

    public TestContext(string databaseName)
        : base(databaseName)
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

The `DbContext` builds the connection with a database providing the database name in the base constructor. Therefore you can control the database it connects to through the constructor.

The databases' connection strings must be declared in the `.config` file of course. For example:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="TestDBContext1" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=TestDB1; persist security info=True; user id=sa; password=saexpress;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="TestDBContext2" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=TestDB2; persist security info=True; user id=sa; password=saexpress;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My advice would be, though, not to use directly the constructors, but rather use the *factory design pattern* to create the appropriate instances of the `DbContext`.

Answer (score 0):

In Entity Framework, the `DbContext` class represents a certain database layout. The `DbSet<TEntity>` in the `DbContext` represent the tables in this database; the non-virtual properties of `TEntity` represent the columns of the table and the virtual properties of `TEntity` represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

If you want a different instance of the database, with exactly the same layout, it is enough to create a different instance of the database with a different 'NameOrConnectionString` as input parameter in the constructor.

If you want a very similar database, where you want to re-use some tables and relations from the other database, you should create a different `DbContext` class; after all: the `DbContext` class represents your database layout, and a different layout means a different DbContext.

It could be that in this second `DbContext` you also want different relations, of different string lengths, different table names, (etc) than the default entity framework values. In that case it is better to use Fluent API in your `DbContext.OnModelCreating`, instead of attributes in your entity classes. This way you can re-use the same entity classes while giving them different column names, string lengths, decimal precisions etc.